# Why did Allah encourage people to come to the Prophet (pbuh) so that he would plead to Allah for forgiveness for them?

Tags: tafseer

In Surah Nisa, verse 64 we read:

> **ما أَرْسَلْنا مِنْ رَسُولٍ إِلاَّ لِيُطاعَ بِإِذْنِ اللَّهِ وَ لَوْ أَنَّهُمْ إِذْ ظَلَمُوا أَنْفُسَهُمْ جاؤُكَ فَاسْتَغْفَرُوا اللَّهَ وَ
>   اسْتَغْفَرَ لَهُمُ الرَّسُولُ لَوَجَدُوا اللَّهَ تَوَّاباً رَحيماً**
>
> **We did not send any apostle but to be obeyed by Allah's leave. Had they, when they wronged themselves, come to you and pleaded to Allah
>   for forgiveness, and the Apostle had pleaded for forgiveness for them,
>   they would have surely found Allah all-clement, all-merciful** [4:64]

My questions are:

- What is the point in encouraging people to come to the Prophet (pbuh) so that he would beg for forgiveness for them?
- Is there anything wrong with begging Allah for forgiveness without coming to the Prophet (pbuh)?
- If they had pleaded to Allah for forgiveness without coming to the Prophet, would have they still found Allah all-clement, all-merciful?

Comment: To show that Allah is **really** The Most Merciful... :)

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed a good question asked and the answer will be as good insha-Allah'

Allah (SWT) says:

> "And whoever does a wrong or wrongs himself but then seeks forgiveness
>   of Allah will find Allah Forgiving and Merciful."(**surah an-nisa, verse:110**)

So there is no question that Allah (SWT) would be merciful or not.

You can similarly see:

> "And those who, when they commit an immorality or wrong themselves [by
>   transgression], remember Allah and seek forgiveness for their sins -
>   and who can forgive sins except Allah ? - and [who] do not persist in
>   what they have done while they know."(**surah al-Im'ran verse:135**)

Now coming to your another question that what is the point of encouragement? 
The answer is as simple, as Almighty wants to lift the status of our beloved prophet (PBUH) and make people understand the real way of seeking forgiveness because the guidance of our beloved prophet (PBUH) is best. Also Almighty himself says to prophet (PBUH) to pray for your people. You can see:

> "Take, [O, Muhammad], from their wealth a charity by which you purify
>   them and cause them increase, and invoke [ Allah 's blessings] upon
>   them. Indeed, your invocations are reassurance for them. And Allah is
>   Hearing and Knowing."(**surah at-Tauba verse:103**)

your 3rd question is there anything wrong I would here like to quote the verse from the glorious Qur'an:

> "And whatever the Messenger has given you - take; and what he has
>   forbidden you - refrain from."(**al-hashr verse:7**)

So this blessing is from prophet (PBUH) so why will one refuse it.. ? 
And what Allah (SWT) knows, we know not!

Comment: Fair enough! But can we also ask the prophet to pray for us now when that he is not physically among us?

Comment: I should say if Allah(SWT) wills to do the same!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean if Allah (SWT) wishes to made prophet (PBUH) do so then why can't? As Almighty has mentioned the above verse in the Quran that means it is for eternity. one can't limit it by any means!

Comment: @infatuated good question, NO!. Those verses meant only for that time and are not applicable now. You cannot ask Prophet(pbuh) now, it would be considered SHIRK. But, you can ask Allah, "With the support of your beloved Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him), FORGIVE ME .... ", verily Allah is all hearer, Oft Forgiving, Most Merciful.